# How can I centre the title of the table of contents in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to centre the title of the table of contents in LaTeX with the following command

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Table of Contents}
```

As I'm asking I'm sure you've all realised that this didn't work, any suggestions on what I can try?

**Edit**: I got it working with

```
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Huge}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This works (without the usepackage):

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Contents}
```

Make sure it's in the preamble, perhaps, and try killing the `.aux` file.

Comment: It works in documentclass `article` and `report`, but produces errors in `book`.

Answer (score 5):

This works in `\documentclass{book}`, without needing the usepackage:

```
\renewcommand*\contentsname{\hfill Contents \hfill}
\tableofcontents
```

It should even work if the \renewcommand is immediately before the \tableofcontents command.

Answer (score 3):

Renewing contentsname may fail because of how \begin{document} rewrites components from babel, such that the commands must be added to \captionsenglish. [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153198/164981) goes into more detail.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
```

Comment: This saved my day after many hours of not understanding why `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Other title}` didnt work